# How to re position the breadcrumb on the product detail page?

Tags: commerce

I am a bit confused, I was wondering how do you re position the breadcrumb to the top of the page. Please see image example below. When I see the default layout of [Drupal Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), the breadcrumb is located on the top of the product. I even replaced the css with the default css and there was no changes.

[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Comment: check your theme's page.tpl.php. and check where `$breadcrumb` is rendered.

Comment: It's not just the breadcrumb - the tabs are at the bottom of the page as well. I would check the html and see if it is actually rendered after the content, for me it seems like some css/template problem. Where/how do you style the content area with the picture and add to cart button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this issue out, I had to look into the Block configuration and adjust the region.